# Memory leak with too many images

Tags: fpdf

I have this script

```
set_time_limit(0);
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
for($x=0;$x<5000;$x++)
{
    $pdf->AddPage('P',array(500,1000));
    $pdf->Image("image".$x,0,0);
}
$pdf->Output();
```

And I set `memory_limit=1000MB` in `php.ini` but nothing happens.

And if I stop the `for` after 20 times, it works.

Why? How can I make it work for the 5000 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer!

You must add the `memory_limit` in the `php.ini`.

(The line is like 'memory_limit=8M;` by default).

P.S: Don't forget to restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used FPDF and its documentation is terrible, but i guess you can $pdf->Close() and start over.
You could also try **FPDF::Close** it should deallocate the memory.

Without a memory pool, which I think it's impossible with php you'll have to new / delete alot.